# How to enable the Update notification in the Unity notification area?

Tags: unity, updates, notification-area

In classic Gnome, We used to have a special notification that appears in the notification area every time system updates are available; I don't see any update notification in Unity. How to enable it so I don't have to check for updates myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can get notified via Unity Launcher.

1. Open your Dash (press <kbd>Super</kbd>) and query for Software Sources to open it.

   [image: dash]
2. In the <kbd>Updates</kbd> tab, modify the settings for `Automatically check for updates:`, `When there are security updates:` and `When there are other updates:`as per your wish.

   [image: software-sources]
3. Now when there would be any updates available, you would be notified via Launcher.

   [image: launcher notification]

Answer (score 0):

If you press power/settings button then
an option will come as "Software Up to date" if no new updates are available.
but if new updates are available it'll say something like "Update Software" or "make software up to date". 
I think this is the new updates notification.

Comment: Which means I have to check it myself ;-). Any other "automated" solution?