# How to disable update notification for all users?

Tags: update-manager, remote, administration, gconf

This is a partial case of the more general question ["Don't bother non-admin users with admin questions"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66886/how-to-enable-the-update-notification-in-the-unity-notification-area):

I have several non-admin users on a computer and I want to disable software updates for all of them. I tried this:

```
# su wife -c gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

(I am logged on to the computer being administered via `ssh`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer versions of Ubuntu, there is a (hidden) per-user config option for this.

Just run (as the user for whom you want to disable notifications):

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications true
```

Or, if you prefer doing things visually, run `dconf-editor`, browse to `/com/ubuntu/update-notifier` and enable the `no-show-notifications` option.

([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1139779))

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be to use `gconftool` to set `auto_launch` to `false` for myself (without `sudo`) and then to copy the config file to all the other user accounts:

```
for u in wife ${kids}; do 
  cp -fv /home/me/.gconf/apps/update-notifier/%gconf.xml /home/$u/.gconf/apps/update-notifier/%gconf.xml
  chown -v $u:$u /home/$u/.gconf/apps/update-notifier/%gconf.xml
done
```