# Updates disabled, Software Updater still popping up

Tags: updates, update-manager

In **Software & Updates** I have **auto check** set to *Never*. Despite this Software Updater launches regularly, telling me about new updates.

What's the problem? What have I accomplished by setting auto updates to never, and why is it seemingly not respected?

#### Affected versions

- *Ubuntu 20.10*
- *Ubuntu MATE 18.04.4*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop apt from doing anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006189/how-to-stop-apt-from-doing-anything) , check [my answer there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006199/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks, disabling the timers might work, although their descriptions are pretty vague. I'll give it a try. But there's still the question of what I accomplished by setting auto updates to Never, and why it's seemingly not respected...

Comment: Your choices are supposed to be respected. Please file a bug report with sufficient detail for the problem to be reproduced on a clean-install in a test environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I utterly stop automatic update checks in Ubuntu 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139545/how-do-i-utterly-stop-automatic-update-checks-in-ubuntu-19-04) I think that question, and its answers, apply to 18.04 as well. (On the other hand, that doesn't really answer the question of "What have I accomplished by setting auto updates to never".)

Comment: @EliahKagan Removing `update-notifier` or `update-manager` removes the mate desktop package. I guess that won't end well later on.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'll try the last two answers, wait, and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @EliahKagan No, those answers don't appear to have any effect on the issue. I was prompted for updates today.